# EventReceiver doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, eventreceiver

I've got an `EventReceiver` in my **SharePoint** application where I'm overriding `ItemAdding` and `ItemUpdating` methods:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();

   switch (properties.ListTitle)
   {
        //some cases

        case "Employees":
            if (properties.AfterProperties["User"] != null)
            {
               SPUser user = web.SiteUsers
               [
                   properties.AfterProperties["User"].ToString().Substring
                   (
                        properties.AfterProperties["User"].ToString().IndexOf(";#") + 2
                    )
               ];

               properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = user.Name;
            }
            break;
   }

   base.ItemAdding(properties);
}
```

Code in both methods is exactly the same. But *sometimes* **Title** field remains empty after adding an item to list. And if I update that item (without any changes) **Title** field is filled by username correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I see two potential issues in your code:

1. processing properties.AfterProperties["User"] by parsing it. It would be better to use code like this (SPUserFieldValue)properties.ListItem.Fields["User"].GetFieldValue(properties.properties.AfterProperties["User"].ToString()). This way suggested by MSDN.
2. Using SiteUsers indexer throws Exception when user is not found in the collection. You should wrap it by try ... catch statement. It can happen when user is used for the first time in your site collection.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to follow you suggestions.